# Launcher missing in CentOS 7 Gnome Desktop

Tags: centos, centos-7

I installed Cent OS 7 in VMware Workstation by selecting Gnome Desktop option.

I don't see the "Create Launcher" and all other options which I used to get in Cent OS 6.5

Did I install incorrect Cent OS7 option?

Also, CentOS 7 seems to be slower than 6.5 whereas it was supposed to be faster.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `alacarte` to edit your application menu.

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> alacarte  provides a usable GUI for the users to easily add menu items, remove menu items, or otherwise modify the GNOME main menu.

If it's not installed:

```
# yum install alacarte
```

Performance is a very broad subject that depend on so many things, making it difficult to comment. It's also subjective, which is taboo on this site.

Comment: I installed alacarte, now where & how to edit it? Earlier with Cent OS 6.5, it used to appear directly on right click of mouse. Why is it made so difficult with Cent OS 7?

Comment: Gnome 3 doesn't have such a menu as it doesn't support launchers on the desktop by default.  There are hacks to do something similar.  Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/167304/how-to-create-desktop-files-and-new-menu-without-alacarte).  You'll also need to enable `Have filemanager handle the desktop` in Gnome-Tweak-Tools for it to show up on the desktop.  To start `alacarte` in order to edit your main menu, click on `Applications` -> `Sundry` -> `Main Menu`.

Comment: "Gnome 3 ... doesn't support launchers on the desktop by default"
WTF?
Because no user would ever want this?